# how I can modify a code to get empty array too?

Tags: pyspark

I have the following code:

```
L = {'L1': ['us'] }
#df1 = df1.withColumnRenamed("name","OriginalCompanyName")
for key, vals in L.items():
    # regex pattern for extracting vals
    pat = r'\\b(%s)\\b' % '|'.join(vals)

    # extract matching occurrences
    col1 = F.expr("regexp_extract_all(array_join(loc, ' '), '%s')" % pat)

    # Mask the rows with null when there are no matches
    df1 = df1.withColumn(key, F.when((F.size(col1) == 0), None).otherwise(col1))
```

it is extracting `us` from the column `loc` and `key` column is `us` and `null` otherwise. I have also some empty list `[]` in the column `loc`. I want to also put `us` in the column `key` when `loc` is empty. If I change `L = {'L1': ['us'] }` to `L = {'L1': ['us','[]' }` it doesn't work.

For some reason this code actually eliminates rows when `loc` is empty. Can I modify the code?

**Hint:** empty `loc` can be found by the following code:

`df1=df1.withColumn('empty_country', when(sf.size('loc')==0,'us'))`

data sample

```
loc
["this is ,us, better life"]
["no one is, in charge"]
["I am, very far, from us"]
[]


loc
["this is ,us, better life"]      ["us"]
["no one is, in charge"]           null
["I am, very far, from us"]        ["us"]
[]                                 ["us"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make this change to the last line in the `for` loop:

```
df1 = df1.withColumn(key, f.when((f.size(col1) == 0) & (f.size('loc')!=0), None).when(f.size('loc')==0, f.array(f.lit('us'))).otherwise(col1))
```

PS: The output of `regexp_extract_all` is an array.